# How to test mobile apps on different devices

Tags: testing, device

I want to test my IOS,Android and hybrid apps on various virtual devices. Please suggest me a good tool that can perform these functions.

Answer (score 0):

We currently use Genymotion for testing with Android and XCode's simulator for iOS. These will allow you test a wide range of iOS/Android devices.

If you are looking for one tool to test both iOS and Android I believe Visual Studio's Xamarin supports both, there is also a browser based solution with appetize.io. I haven't used either of those so can't comment on if they are any good.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of chrome developer toolbar it has most of the device options like device horizontal/Vertical, Zoom

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You get the different versions along with the different screen sizes in the simulator which you are working.
Eg: IOS(xcode) when you build it you get which version to build when running the application. Same for Android and hybrid apps